# Laravel syncWithoutDetaching with extra fields

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

I am trying to save a simple `belongsToMany` relation into my database. First, my table:

```php
Schema::create('user_activity_log', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('activity_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('log_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('sets');
    $table->unsignedInteger('reps');
    $table->primary(['activity_id', 'log_id']);
    $table->foreign('activity_id')->references('id')->on('user_activities')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreign('log_id')->references('id')->on('user_logs')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

My `Log` and `Activity` models have these relations:

Log:

```php
public function activities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Activity::class, 'user_activity_log', 'log_id', 'activity_id')
        ->withPivot(['sets', 'reps']);
}
```

Activity:

```php
public function logs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Log::class, 'user_activity_log', 'activity_id', 'log_id')
        ->withPivot(['sets', 'reps']);
}
```

When adding a new activity to an existing log, in my store method I am doing simply this:

```php
$log->activities()->syncWithoutDetaching([
    $request->input('activity_id') => [
        'sets' => $request->input('sets'),
        'reps' => $request->input('reps')
    ]
]);
```

I am getting this error:

```text
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' 
select * from `user_activity_log` where `id` = 0 limit 1
```

The data IS being saved though, so when I refresh the page and thus submit the form again, there are no errors. I cannot figure out why it is trying to find the `id` in the `user_activity_log` table.

Comment: I created the tables, models, but not getting that error after adding a new activity.
Are you sure it is related to this syncWithoutDetaching? Can you post the models, controllers related to this issue?

Comment: Agree with above comment, I also tried and works fine. First thing to check is whether the `syncWithoutDetaching` is what's actually causing the error. I would suggest going through the full stack trace of the error, it will contain which line from your code the error occurred ( basically, find the first line from the stack trace that is not from vendor folder )

Comment: Thanks, I will post some more info and of course check this a bit more in-depth

Comment: After trying again today, there are no errors... So if anyone could post an answer to get the bounty that would be nice :)

Comment: If anyone could post an answer so I could give the bounty to someone that woule be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more investigating it seems that it was an issue with the [Spatie Activitylog](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/introduction). Nothing with the naming of my models etc though. What the issue is exactly is still being investigated.

So I was using a pivot model "ActivityLog", to log the activity on the pivot table. But I forgot to add a primary key to the `activity_log` table. So this had totally nothing to do with `attach` or `syncWithoutDetaching` indeed.